# SQL*loader does not load XML

Tags: xml, oracle, sql-loader

I am trying to load XML data exactly according to the Oracle documentation: [https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/xdb25loa.htm#ADXDB5731]

But the only result is the error:

```
SQL*Loader: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Mon Mar 6 11:15:26 2023
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

SQL*Loader-416: SDF clause for field XML_ in table FOP2 references a non existent field.
```

I do not know, what is wrong, because table FOP2 exists, it was created by:
`CREATE TABLE FOP2 (XML_ XMLTYPE);`

It is loaded by:
`sqlldr usr/psw loader.ctl`

loader.ctl is matching the Oracle documentation as much as possible:

```
load data
infile 'filenames.dat'
APPEND
into table FOP2 
xmltype(XML_)
(
 XML_ lobfile(filename) terminated by eof
)
```

filenames.dat contains just one filename:
`C:\Users\PP\Downloads\datafile-seznam_ds_pfo-20230302094107.xml`

And the xml filename is:

```
    <box>
        <id>8iedd6n</id>
        <type>XXX</type>
        <subtype>16</subtype>
        <name>
            <person>
                <firstName></firstName>
                <lastName></lastName>
            </person>
            <tradeName>BBB</tradeName>
        </name>
        <ico>12345678</ico>
        <address>
            <city>CCC</city>
            <district>DDD</district>
            <street>FFF</street>
            <cp>GGG</cp>
            <co>HHH</co>
            <ce></ce>
            <zip>11111</zip>
            <addressPoint></addressPoint>
            <state>CZ</state>
            <fullAddress></fullAddress>
        </address>
        <pdz>false</pdz>
        <ovm>true</ovm>
        <hierarchy>
            <isMaster>true</isMaster>
        </hierarchy>
        <idOVM>22222222</idOVM>
    </box>
    <box>
        <id>9jic8np</id>
        <type>XXX</type>
        <subtype>20</subtype>
        <name>
            <person>
                <firstName></firstName>
                <lastName></lastName>
            </person>
            <tradeName>CCC</tradeName>
        </name>
        <ico>12345678</ico>
        <address>
            <city>DDD/city>
            <district>EEE</district>
            <street>FFF</street>
            <cp>333</cp>
            <co>44</co>
            <ce></ce>
            <zip>55555</zip>
            <addressPoint>123456789</addressPoint>
            <state>CZ</state>
            <fullAddress></fullAddress>
        </address>
        <pdz>false</pdz>
        <ovm>true</ovm>
        <hierarchy>
            <isMaster>true</isMaster>
        </hierarchy>
        <idOVM>33333333</idOVM>
    </box>
```

So, where is the problem? Everything is like in the Oracle documentation, I tried to repeat it in all details, but it does not work. I cannot get through.

I tried to find answer on the forum, I tried to modify the load in many different ways, without success. Finally I tried to write almost identical code with the Oracle documentation, which I am presenting here, but still there is error. I would be happy to understand, what is wrong, how to make it working.

Comment: For starters,, try using the documentation for the correct version of Oracle (which for you appears to be 19c), and see if that gets you any further: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adxdb/how-to-load-XML-data.html#GUID-8D779EF9-564F-43DA-96B2-0CD0A5177008

Comment: You are missing an angle bracket for second city DDD : ` </city>1

Comment: Oracle documentation for v.19 is exactly the same:  https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adxdb/how-to-load-XML-data.html#GUID-9B6141F4-E606-4365-B1EF-2BA391A43C09

Comment: Yes, but it does not work even with  <city>DDD</city>.  It does not start reading the XML.

Comment: But finally GPTChat provided correct answer. There is mistake in Oracle documentation. There is an example of ctl file:
load data
infile 'filelist.dat'
append
into table PURCHASEORDER
xmltype(XMLDATA) 
(
 filename filler char(120),
 XMLDATA  lobfile(filename) terminated by eof
).
.ctl file, which is working, is:
load data
infile 'datafile-seznam_ds_pfo-20230302094107.xml'
APPEND
into table FOP2 
(
 XML_ lobfile(constant 'datafile-seznam_ds_pfo-20230302094107.xml') terminated by eof
) 
Ie. without
 xmltype(XMLDATA)

Answer (score 0):

the "non existent field" the error message references to is "filename", the documentation example has "filename filler char(120)" that you removed.

Comment: GPTChat provided correct answer. There is mistake in Oracle documentation. There is an example of ctl file: load data infile 'filelist.dat' append into table PURCHASEORDER xmltype(XMLDATA) ( filename filler char(120), XMLDATA lobfile(filename) terminated by eof ). .ctl file, which is working, is: load data infile 'datafile-seznam_ds_pfo-20230302094107.xml' APPEND into table FOP2 ( XML_ lobfile(constant 'datafile-seznam_ds_pfo-20230302094107.xml') terminated by eof ) Ie. without xmltype(XMLDATA)

Comment: No, the ctl file works without "filename" statement , it is not the problem. problem is the statement "xmltype(XMLDATA)" .

Answer (score 0):

Just to summarize the problems, I encounter, and their solution:

1. control file, which is working:

   load data

   CHARACTERSET UTF8

   infile 'datafile-seznam_ds_pfo-20230302094107.xml'

   REPLACE

   into table FOP2
   (

   dummy FILLER CHAR(3000) TERMINATED BY "box",

   XML_ lobfile(constant 'datafile-seznam_ds_pfo-20230302094107.xml') terminated by ""

   )
2. But FOP2 table has to be of CLOB type: `CREATE TABLE FOP2 (XML_  CLOB) ;`

3 It creates another problem with parsing the fields. This does not work, because xml_ is of CLOB type. And conversion xmltype.createxml also does not work, because of some records (there are many empty records, I did not find how to remove them from load):

```
SELECT x.*
FROM   
 FOP2
 CROSS JOIN
 XMLTABLE (
  'BOX'
  PASSING xmltype.createxml(FOP2.xml_)
  COLUMNS 
   id          varchar2(10)  PATH './id' ,
   type        varchar2(10)  PATH './type' ,
   subtype     varchar2(10)  PATH './subtype' ,
   firstName   varchar2(50)  PATH './name/person/firstName' ,
   lastName    varchar2(50)  PATH './name/person/lastName' ,
   tradeName   varchar2(50)  PATH './name/tradeName' ,
   ico         varchar2(10)  PATH './ico' ,
   city        varchar2(100) PATH './address/city' ,
   district    varchar2(100) PATH './address/district' ,
   street      varchar2(100) PATH './address/street' ,
   cp          varchar2(10)  PATH './address/cp' ,      
   co          varchar2(10)  PATH './address/co' ,     
   ce          varchar2(10)  PATH './address/ce' ,      
   zip         varchar2(10)  PATH './address/zip' ,       
   state       varchar2(10)  PATH './address/state' ,
   pdz         varchar2(10)  PATH './pdz' , 
   ovm         varchar2(10)  PATH './ovm' ,
   isMaster    varchar2(10)  PATH './hierarchy/isMaster' ,
   idOVM       varchar2(10)  PATH './idOVM' 
 ) x
;
```

4. But the code, which is working, is simply manual parsing.
   Condition, which removes empty records, works (where instr( xml_, 'box',1) != 0;) :

   select
   XML_ ,

   substr(XML_,
   instr(XML_,'',1)+4 ,
   instr(XML_,'', (instr(XML_,'',1)+4))-(instr(XML_,'',1)+4)
   ) as id ,

   substr(XML_,
   instr(XML_,'',1)+6 ,
   instr(XML_,'', (instr(XML_,'',1)+6))-(instr(XML_,'',1)+6)
   ) as type ,

   substr(XML_,
   instr(XML_,'',1)+9 ,
   instr(XML_,'', (instr(XML_,'',1)+9))-(instr(XML_,'',1)+9)
   ) as subtype ,

   substr(XML_,
   instr(XML_,'',1)+11 ,
   instr(XML_,'', (instr(XML_,'',1)+11))-(instr(XML_,'',1)+11)
   ) as firstName ,

   substr(XML_,
   instr(XML_,'',1)+10 ,
   instr(XML_,'', (instr(XML_,'',1)+10))-(instr(XML_,'',1)+10)
   ) as lastName ,

   substr(XML_,
   instr(XML_,'',1)+5 ,
   instr(XML_,'', (instr(XML_,'',1)+5))-(instr(XML_,'',1)+5)
   ) as ico ,

   substr(XML_,
   instr(XML_,'',1)+6 ,
   instr(XML_,'', (instr(XML_,'',1)+6))-(instr(XML_,'',1)+6)
   ) as city ,

   substr(XML_,
   instr(XML_,'',1)+10 ,
   instr(XML_,'', (instr(XML_,'',1)+10))-(instr(XML_,'',1)+10)
   ) as district ,

   substr(XML_,
   instr(XML_,'',1)+8 ,
   instr(XML_,'', (instr(XML_,'',1)+8))-(instr(XML_,'',1)+8)
   ) as street ,

   substr(XML_,
   instr(XML_,'',1)+4 ,
   instr(XML_,'', (instr(XML_,'',1)+4))-(instr(XML_,'',1)+4)
   ) as cp ,

   substr(XML_,
   instr(XML_,'',1)+4 ,
   instr(XML_,'', (instr(XML_,'',1)+4))-(instr(XML_,'',1)+4)
   ) as co ,

   substr(XML_,
   instr(XML_,'',1)+4 ,
   instr(XML_,'', (instr(XML_,'',1)+4))-(instr(XML_,'',1)+4)
   ) as ce ,

   substr(XML_,
   instr(XML_,'',1)+5 ,
   instr(XML_,'', (instr(XML_,'',1)+5))-(instr(XML_,'',1)+5)
   ) as zip ,

   substr(XML_,
   instr(XML_,'',1)+7 ,
   instr(XML_,'', (instr(XML_,'',1)+7))-(instr(XML_,'',1)+7)
   ) as state

   from
   FOP2
   where
   instr( xml_, 'box',1) != 0;
5. I have noticed one more problem in  the load data. There is one record with full

   ' version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"'

So, apparetly the row

```
dummy FILLER CHAR(3000) TERMINATED BY "<box>",
```

does not work correctly.

But manual parsing of the CLOB has no problem with such a record. I would guess that XML parser would have a problem, because record is in different format than others.

The question is, why `dummy FILLER CHAR(3000) TERMINATED BY "<box>",` does not work.